# Using a constrained type in generic method

Tags: java, generics

Consider an interface `HasWord` and a class `Word` that implements it. The following is a cut-down class that is trying to feed a `List<Word>` to a `Consumer` with a type parameter from the generic function. What rule am I missing about how to do this?

```
public static <T extends HasWord> void mapOverSentencesOfTokens(String input,
                                            Consumer<List<T>> consumer) {
    List<Word> sentenceForTagger = new ArrayList<>();
    consumer.accept(sentenceForTagger);

}
```

I asked this question poorly, I didn't think this through. I'll distribute some upvotes and slink away.

Comment: How can the compiler verify that your `T` is a `Word`? What if I called `mapOverSentencesOfTokens` with an inferred type of `OtherWordTypeHasWord`? Your consumer should only be able to accept lists of that type.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared a `Consumer<List<T>>`.

So the `accept` method expects a `List<T>` as its parameter.

What you are passing, `sentenceForTagger`, is of type `List<Word>` not `List<T>`.

So the compiler complains.

You could declare `List<Word>` as `List<T>` but then you wouldn't be able to add a `Word` to that list for the same reason.

The correct method here would be:

```
public static void mapOverSentencesOfTokens(String input, Consumer<List<HasWord>> consumer) {
    List<HasWord> sentenceForTagger = new ArrayList<>();
    sentenceForTagger.add(new Word());
    consumer.accept(sentenceForTagger);
}
```

Or:

```
public class Example<T extends HasWord> {

    private List<T> sentenceForTagger = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(final T word) {
        sentenceForTagger.add(word);
    }

    public void mapOverSentencesOfTokens(String input, Consumer<List<T>> consumer) {
        consumer.accept(sentenceForTagger);
    }
}
```